# Find Open Form from Sender

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have 24 buttons that each open a separate form. I want to have one method for opening/**bringing each to the front** when clicked on all of them so I don't have to make a separate method for each button click, so that it looks something like this:

```
    private void OpenForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Type type = sender.GetType();
        var existingInstance = Application.OpenForms.OfType<type>().Single();
        existingInstance.BringToFront();
    }
```

but then I get the error "'type' is a variable but is used like a type.

I've looked at many other forums on Stack Overflow and none have given me a solution. Maybe what I'm trying to accomplish isn't possible?

Comment: OpenForms is about Forms, so `Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>()`. `sender` is the Button. You need something that *links* a Button to a Form. You could use the `Button.Tag` to hold this information. Then you need `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.Single()`. It may not be opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary to link between buttons to forms:

```
Dictionary<Button, Form> _buttonToFormDict = new Dictionary<Button, Form>();
```

Add buttons and forms to the dictionary in your code:

```
_buttonToFormDict.Add(button1, _form1);
_buttonToFormDict.Add(button2, _form2);
_buttonToFormDict.Add(button3, _form3);
...
```

Add a button click event that checks what button was clicked and finds the related form:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (sender is Button && _buttonToFormDict.ContainsKey(btn))
    {
        Form form = _buttonToFormDict[btn];
        if (!form.IsDisposed && form != null)
        {
            // Show the form if it was not shown
            form.Show();

            // Bring back the form if it was minimized
            if (form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }

            // Brig to front
            form.BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

And add the click event to the button's click event.

Comment: What is "_form1" in your case? When I try to directly reference my form it tells me it's a "type, which is not valid in the given context."

Comment: @EthanShoe: "_form1", "_form2", "_form3" and "button1", "button2", "button3" are just examples, replace them with your own forms and buttons

Comment: I understand, but when I did it gave me the error I mentioned in my first comment, saying it was a type.

Comment: @EthanShoe: Not sure what's causing the error, I did a simple example with 3 forms and 3 buttons an it works.

Comment: @EthanShoe - You don't use the name of your Form class in the dictionary, you use the variable name of the instance of the class.  `Form1 _form1 = new Form1();  _buttonToFormDict.Add(button1, _form1);`  Or you could just use `_buttonToFormDict.Add(button1, new Form1());`